# How to handle adding of entites with related entities

Tags: entity-framework, frontend, .net-core

I have 2 models

```
  public class Licence
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
   }

  public class Customer
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int LicenceId { get; set; }

    public virtual Licence Licence { get; set; }
  }
```

I want to create my licence with an existing customer

```
[HttpPut]
public IActionResult CreateLicence([FromBody]Licence licence)
{
  Context.Add(licence);
  Context.SaveChanges();

  return Ok(licence);
}
```

I have several options now :

1.I can initialize the LicenceId on the Frontend with

```
Licence.CustomerId = (Selected Customer.CustomerId)
```

2.I can initialize the Licence on the Frontend with

```
Licence.Customer = (Selected Customer Object)
```

When I do 2 I need an extesion methode which I wrote to ignore navigation properties who alreasy exists.
I personally like 2 because of its smaller code, and ef create these navigation properties by his own.

> public int CustomerId { get; set; }

Can someone say me what the right way is to do this? 1. or 2?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got from your question: You want to save License object but by adding "CustomerID" in it as License table would have CustomerID as foreign Key.

If I understood you right: You should go with approach 1. Navigation property is helpful when you read data. Or if you are going to create child data then you need to fill relevant navigation properties.